# How to override the font text color in the filter part of react-data-table-component-extensions?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-data-table-component

need some help on this sir,

I'm using react-data-table-component and react-data-table-component-extensions.
also, I imported the index.css for the component-extension

```
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import DataTableExtensions from "react-data-table-component-extensions";
import "react-data-table-component-extensions/dist/index.css";
```

the code for dataTable in jsx file is below

```
<DataTableExtensions
        columns={column}
        data={parameters}
        print={false}
        export={false}
        filterPlaceholder="Filter Parameter"
      >
        <DataTable
          title="Parameter List"
          columns={column}
          data={parameters}
          pageSize={5}
          pagination
          fixedHeader
          fixedHeaderScrollHeight="450px"
          highlightOnHover
          actions={<AddParameter loadParameters={loadParameters} />}
        />
      </DataTableExtensions>
```

my problem is on the display side, the font doesn't match the existing background of the app. It is so dark.

[image: DataTable]

I wanted to make the text to the color white. but I am unable to style the react data table extension component.

I tried locating the index.css which I am importing and tried to manipulate
some css there but No effect. tried also removing all the CSS inside the index.css
also no effect.

Am I editing the wrong css file or this is not editable?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass CSS to change the font color as desired using the below code in your css file to change font color in the filter part of react-data-table-component-extension. I'm sharing my complete code by which you can style the border and border radius as well. You can select the required properties.

```
.data-table-extensions>.data-table-extensions-filter>.filter-text { 
  
   border: var(--bs-border-width) solid var(--bs-border-color) !important; 
   border-radius: var(--bs-border-radius) !important; 
   outline: none; 
   transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out !important; 
   font-size: 1rem !important; 
   font-weight: 400 !important; 
   line-height: 1.5 !important; 
   color: var(--bs-body-color) !important; 
   background-color: var(--bs-body-bg); 
   background-clip: padding-box !important; 
   font-family: inherit !important; 
 }
```

Comment: React-Data-Table Component is still continuing to amaze me. Today found it's documentation really helpful in in-fixing the below issues:
1. Setting serial number
2. Fixing horizontal scroll
3. Using selectable rows.

He's the link for complete documentation. Feel free to let me know in case of any ambiguity:
https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/getting-started-intro--page